# Estimating the focus plane of camera via thin lens equation

Tags: optics, lenses, software, camera, image-processing

I have a camera that outputs a JSON file for every image taken. In the JSON file, I can find camera-specific and also the photo-specific acquisition parameters used. The issue is I wish to estimate the focus plane distance of a photo exactly, so I wish to use the JSON file to do so. Assuming the thin lens equation holds,
$$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{z_o}+\frac{1}{z_i}$$
where $o$ is the real object and $i$ is the image.

Solving for $z_o$ I would expect to get the distance in front of the camera in which the camera is in focus. 
Based on what I focused on, the focus plane should be $20$-$30\mathrm{cm}$ in front of the camera. Searching the JSON file for parameters I find a focal length parameter, which according to the camera display was $69\mathrm{mm}$ (after factoring in $3.19$ Crop factor), and what I assume to be is the distance to the image sensor with the exitPupilOffset parameter. Plugging in these values I end up getting 
$$\left(\frac{1}{.02165}-\frac{1}{.083505}\right)^{-1}=z_0$$

I am assuming that the values given in the JSON are expressed in meters, in which case the answer would be $29\mathrm{mm}$, which is nowhere near how far the object actually is. Am I interpreting the JSON wrong, is there the possibility that my JSON file is just uncalibrated?

Attached JSON.

```
  {
"picture": {
  "dcfDirectory": "100PHOTO",
  "dcfFile": "IMG_1010",
  "totalFrames": 1,
  "frameIndex": 0
},
"generator": "lightning",
"settings": {
  "flash": {
    "exposureCompensation": 0.0,
    "curtainTriggerSync": "front",
    "zoomMode": "auto",
    "mode": "unknown",
    "afAssistMode": "auto"
  },
  "focus": {
    "roi": [
      {
        "top": 0.0,
        "right": 1.0,
        "left": 0.0,
        "bottom": 1.0
      }
    ],
    "afDriveMode": "manual",
    "bracketCount": 3,
    "bracketOffset": 0.0,
    "bracketStep": 3.0,
    "bracketEnable": false,
    "mode": "auto",
    "afActuationMode": "single",
    "ringLock": false,
    "captureLambda": -4.0
  },
  "zoom": {
    "ringLock": false
  },
  "shutter": {
    "driveMode": "single",
    "selfTimerEnable": false,
    "selfTimerDuration": 10.0
  },
  "depth": {
    "histogram": "off",
    "assist": "off",
    "overlay": "off"
  },
  "whiteBalance": {
    "cct": 2917,
    "tint": -14.0,
    "mode": "auto"
  },
  "exposure": {
    "bracketCount": 3,
    "meter": {
      "roiMode": "af",
      "roi": [
        {
          "top": 0.0,
          "right": 1.0,
          "left": 0.0,
          "bottom": 1.0
        }
      ],
      "mode": "evaluative"
    },
    "bracketOffset": 0.0,
    "bracketStep": 1.0,
    "compensation": -2.0606489181518555,
    "bracketEnable": false,
    "mode": "manual",
    "aeLock": false
  }
},
"image": {
  "pixelPacking": {
    "bitsPerPixel": 10,
    "endianness": "little"
  },
  "orientation": 1,
  "color": {
    "ccm": [
      2.0307798385620117,
      -0.574540913105011,
      -0.45623892545700073,
      -0.5976311564445496,
      1.8244290351867676,
      -0.22679781913757324,
      -0.7936299443244934,
      -1.610772967338562,
      3.404402732849121
    ],
    "whiteBalanceGain": {
      "r": 1.0,
      "b": 1.8171261548995972,
      "gr": 1.0173076391220093,
      "gb": 1.0173076391220093
    }
  },
  "height": 5368,
  "width": 7728,
  "pixelFormat": {
    "black": {
      "r": 65,
      "b": 65,
      "gr": 65,
      "gb": 65
    },
    "white": {
      "r": 1023,
      "b": 1023,
      "gr": 1023,
      "gb": 1023
    },
    "rightShift": 0
  },
  "modulationExposureBias": -0.2632111608982086,
  "iso": 125,
  "originOnSensor": {
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  },
  "limitExposureBias": 0.0,
  "mosaic": {
    "tile": "r,gr:gb,b",
    "upperLeftPixel": "gr"
  }
},
"devices": {
  "shutter": {
    "pixelExposureDuration": 0.050014421343803406,
    "maxSyncSpeed": 0.004,
    "frameExposureDuration": 0.050014421343803406,
    "mechanism": "focalPlaneCurtain"
  },
  "mla": {
    "scaleFactor": {
      "y": 1.000274658203125,
      "x": 1.0
    },
    "lensPitch": 2e-05,
    "sensorOffset": {
      "y": 1.3719854354858398e-06,
      "x": 3.7586116790771486e-06,
      "z": 3.7e-05
    },
    "rotation": 0.0004427027015481144,
    "tiling": "hexUniformRowMajor",
    "config": "com.lytro.mla.3"
  },
  "accelerometer": {
    "samples": [
      {
        "y": 9.672821044921875,
        "x": -0.8846282958984375,
        "z": 0.53753662109375,
        "time": 0.0
      }
    ]
  },
  "clock": {
    "isTimeValid": true,
    "zuluTime": "2019-06-21T22:30:09.765Z"
  },
  "battery": {
    "cycleCount": 13,
    "model": "B01-3760",
    "make": "Lytro",
    "chargeLevel": 96
  },
  "lens": {
    "fNumber": 2.1714898266121816,
    "focalLength": 0.02165041380790351,
    "opticalCenterOffset": {
      "y": -3.0073242669459432e-06,
      "x": -7.64151627663523e-05
    },
    "infinityLambda": 51.51889459300562,
    "focusStep": 289,
    "zoomStep": -222,
    "exitPupilOffset": {
      "z": 0.08305148315429688
    }
  },
  "sensor": {
    "analogGain": {
      "r": 1.5625,
      "b": 1.5625,
      "gr": 1.5625,
      "gb": 1.5625
    },
    "pixelWidth": 7728,
    "perCcm": [
      {
        "ccm": [
          2.006272077560425,
          -0.5362802147865295,
          -0.46999192237854004,
          -0.6019303798675537,
          1.836044430732727,
          -0.23411400616168976,
          -0.8173090815544128,
          -1.6435128450393677,
          3.4608218669891357
        ],
        "cct": 2850.0
      },
      {
        "ccm": [
          2.4793264865875244,
          -1.2747985124588013,
          -0.20452789962291718,
          -0.5189455151557922,
          1.6118407249450684,
          -0.09289517253637314,
          -0.3602483570575714,
          -1.0115599632263184,
          2.3718082904815674
        ],
        "cct": 4150.0
      },
      {
        "ccm": [
          2.1902196407318115,
          -1.0231428146362305,
          -0.16707684099674225,
          -0.4134329855442047,
          1.7654914855957031,
          -0.3520585000514984,
          -0.18222910165786743,
          -0.7082417607307434,
          1.8904708623886108
        ],
        "cct": 6500.0
      }
    ],
    "bitsPerPixel": 10,
    "baseIso": 80,
    "pixelPitch": 1.4e-06,
    "normalizedResponses": [
      {
        "cct": 5100,
        "r": 0.7512235641479492,
        "b": 0.7596154808998108,
        "gb": 1.0,
        "gr": 1.0
      }
    ],
    "pixelHeight": 5368,
    "mosaic": {
      "tile": "r,gr:gb,b",
      "upperLeftPixel": "gr"
    }
  }
},
"camera": {
  "make": "Lytro, Inc.",
  "firmware": "2.0.0 (42)",
  "model": "ILLUM"
},
"algorithms": {
  "ae": {
    "roi": "followAf",
    "computed": {
      "ev": 1.5625
    },
    "mode": "live"
  },
  "awb": {
    "roi": "fullFrame",
    "computed": {
      "cct": 2917,
      "gain": {
        "r": 1.0,
        "b": 1.8171261548995972,
        "gr": 1.0173076391220093,
        "gb": 1.0173076391220093
      }
    }
  },
  "af": {
    "roi": "focusRoi",
    "computed": {
      "focusStep": 289
    }
  }
},
"schema": "http://schema.lytro.com/lfp/lytro_illum_public/1.3.5/lytro_illum_public_schema.json"
```

Note: that this is a light field camera, which is slightly different than a conventional camera.

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow is more suitable for this question. StackOverflow is about programming.

Comment: @Pers This has nothing to do with programming. It's about interpreting data describing an imaging system.